# Difference between "//" and "/" in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators

Python 2 has two division operators: `/` and `//`. The following output:

```
========================================= RESTART: Shell =========================================
>>> for x in range(10):
        for y in range(1, 10):
                print x,'//',y,'=',x//y
                print x,'/',y,'=',x/y
                print


0 // 1 = 0
0 / 1 = 0

0 // 2 = 0
0 / 2 = 0

0 // 3 = 0
0 / 3 = 0

0 // 4 = 0
0 / 4 = 0

0 // 5 = 0
0 / 5 = 0

0 // 6 = 0
0 / 6 = 0

0 // 7 = 0
0 / 7 = 0

0 // 8 = 0
0 / 8 = 0

0 // 9 = 0
0 / 9 = 0

1 // 1 = 1
1 / 1 = 1

1 // 2 = 0
1 / 2 = 0

1 // 3 = 0
1 / 3 = 0

1 // 4 = 0
1 / 4 = 0

1 // 5 = 0
1 / 5 = 0

1 // 6 = 0
1 / 6 = 0

1 // 7 = 0
1 / 7 = 0

1 // 8 = 0
1 / 8 = 0

1 // 9 = 0
1 / 9 = 0

2 // 1 = 2
2 / 1 = 2

2 // 2 = 1
2 / 2 = 1

2 // 3 = 0
2 / 3 = 0

2 // 4 = 0
2 / 4 = 0

2 // 5 = 0
2 / 5 = 0

2 // 6 = 0
2 / 6 = 0

2 // 7 = 0
2 / 7 = 0

2 // 8 = 0
2 / 8 = 0

2 // 9 = 0
2 / 9 = 0

3 // 1 = 3
3 / 1 = 3

3 // 2 = 1
3 / 2 = 1

3 // 3 = 1
3 / 3 = 1

3 // 4 = 0
3 / 4 = 0

3 // 5 = 0
3 / 5 = 0

3 // 6 = 0
3 / 6 = 0

3 // 7 = 0
3 / 7 = 0

3 // 8 = 0
3 / 8 = 0

3 // 9 = 0
3 / 9 = 0

4 // 1 = 4
4 / 1 = 4

4 // 2 = 2
4 / 2 = 2

4 // 3 = 1
4 / 3 = 1

4 // 4 = 1
4 / 4 = 1

4 // 5 = 0
4 / 5 = 0

4 // 6 = 0
4 / 6 = 0

4 // 7 = 0
4 / 7 = 0

4 // 8 = 0
4 / 8 = 0

4 // 9 = 0
4 / 9 = 0

5 // 1 = 5
5 / 1 = 5

5 // 2 = 2
5 / 2 = 2

5 // 3 = 1
5 / 3 = 1

5 // 4 = 1
5 / 4 = 1

5 // 5 = 1
5 / 5 = 1

5 // 6 = 0
5 / 6 = 0

5 // 7 = 0
5 / 7 = 0

5 // 8 = 0
5 / 8 = 0

5 // 9 = 0
5 / 9 = 0

6 // 1 = 6
6 / 1 = 6

6 // 2 = 3
6 / 2 = 3

6 // 3 = 2
6 / 3 = 2

6 // 4 = 1
6 / 4 = 1

6 // 5 = 1
6 / 5 = 1

6 // 6 = 1
6 / 6 = 1

6 // 7 = 0
6 / 7 = 0

6 // 8 = 0
6 / 8 = 0

6 // 9 = 0
6 / 9 = 0

7 // 1 = 7
7 / 1 = 7

7 // 2 = 3
7 / 2 = 3

7 // 3 = 2
7 / 3 = 2

7 // 4 = 1
7 / 4 = 1

7 // 5 = 1
7 / 5 = 1

7 // 6 = 1
7 / 6 = 1

7 // 7 = 1
7 / 7 = 1

7 // 8 = 0
7 / 8 = 0

7 // 9 = 0
7 / 9 = 0

8 // 1 = 8
8 / 1 = 8

8 // 2 = 4
8 / 2 = 4

8 // 3 = 2
8 / 3 = 2

8 // 4 = 2
8 / 4 = 2

8 // 5 = 1
8 / 5 = 1

8 // 6 = 1
8 / 6 = 1

8 // 7 = 1
8 / 7 = 1

8 // 8 = 1
8 / 8 = 1

8 // 9 = 0
8 / 9 = 0

9 // 1 = 9
9 / 1 = 9

9 // 2 = 4
9 / 2 = 4

9 // 3 = 3
9 / 3 = 3

9 // 4 = 2
9 / 4 = 2

9 // 5 = 1
9 / 5 = 1

9 // 6 = 1
9 / 6 = 1

9 // 7 = 1
9 / 7 = 1

9 // 8 = 1
9 / 8 = 1

9 // 9 = 1
9 / 9 = 1

>>>
```

proves (almost?) all the time `a/b` equals `a//b`. Is there any time that it isn't? If not, why did Python 2 include two operators that do the same thing?

Comment: When applied to integers in Python 2.x, `/` and `//` are exactly the same. Try the same test in Python 3.x and prepare for a surprise. Having two operators was a way of preparing for the future.

Comment: `from __future__ import division`

Comment: The new `//` division operator was introduced by [PEP 238 -- Changing the Division Operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).  To get the "future" (Python 3) style division by default, start your program with the import from [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) that Peter Wood commented above.

Comment: Oops.. sorry. I didn't see that in the "similar" list when I created my question

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`//` is the floored-division operator in Python. The difference is visible when dividing floating point values.

In Python2, dividing two ints uses integer division, which ends up getting you the same thing as floored division. However, you can still use `//` to get a floored result of floating point division.

```
# Python 2
>>> 10.0 / 3
3.3333333333333335
>>> 10.0 // 3
3.0
```

However, in **Python3**, dividing two ints results in a float, but using `//` acts as integer division.

```
# Python3
>>> 10 / 3
3.3333333333333335
>>> 10 // 3
3
```

If you are (still) working in Python2, but want to someday convert to Python3, you should always use `//` when dividing two ints, or use `from __future__ import division` to get the Python3 behavior in Python2

Floored division means round towards negative infinity. This is the same as truncation for positive values, but not for negative. 3.3 rounds down to 3, but -3.3 rounds down to -4.

```
# Python3
>>> -10 // 3
-4
>>> 10 // 3
3
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand.

Comment: In Python 2, you can `from __future__ import division` to get the Python 3 behavior of `/`.

Answer (score 2):

In python 2.7, to do real division you'll need to import division from a module named future:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Then, the `/` will be the real (floating) division, i.e.:

```
15 / 4 => 3.75
```

And the `//` will be the integer division (the integer part of the real division), i.e.:

```
15 // 4 => 3
```